# How to create AWS Glue DynamicFrame from json with array of objects

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, etl, aws-glue

I have json files in S3 containing array of objects in each file, like shown below.

```
[{
    "id": "c147162a-a304-11ea-aa90-0242ac110028",
    "clientId": "xxx",
    "contextUUID": "1bb6b39e-b181-4a6d-b43b-4040f9d254b8",
    "tags": {},
    "timestamp": 1592855898
}, {
    "id": "c147162a-a304-11ea-aa90-0242ac110028",
    "clientId": "yyy",
    "contextUUID": "1bb6b39e-b181-4a6d-b43b-4040f9d254b8",
    "tags": {},
    "timestamp": 1592855898
}]
```

I used crawler to detect and load the schema to catalog. It was successful and it created a schema with a single column named `array` with data type `array<struct<id:string,clientId:string,contextUUID:string,tags:string,timestamp:int>>`.

Now, I tried to load the data using `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` function, but I could not see any data. I tried printing schema and data as shown below.

```
ds = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
       database = "dbname",
       table_name = "tablename")

ds.printSchema()
root
ds.schema()
StructType([], {})
ds.show()
empty
ds.toDF().show()
++
||
++
++
```

Any idea, what I am doing wrong? I am planning to extract each object in array and transform the object to a different schema.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have proper S3 permissions defined on the role for your Glue job to read this data from S3 bucket?

Comment: Yes, the Glue job IAM role has proper S3 permissions.

Comment: ok. then can you do a simple list/get of s3 objects with boto3 inside your Glue job and confirm the same? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2

Comment: sorry for the delay and thanks for the feedback. I had to modify some jsonpath property to $.[*] to evaluate each element in the array as row. Can't remember if that's via UI or code. I will post the solution when I get a chance. Thanks again!

Comment: hey!
I am having same issue. does someone has the solution for it? Permissions look fine as spark.read.json() works fine it just glue_context.create_dynamic_frame which is creating problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give regex in format_options to tell glue how it should read the data. Following code has worked for me:

```
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options('s3', 
    {
        'paths': ["s3://glue-test-bucket-12345/events/101-1.json"]
    },
    format="json", 
    format_options={"jsonPath": "$[*]"}
    ).toDF()
```

I hope it solves the problem.